# Can someone tell me what type of art style is this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, style-identification

I'm still an amateur in graphic design and I saw this style on a comic. Can anyone tell me what type of style is this (the background) if it has a name? The messy, uncoordinated strokes but collectively, it looks super cool.

Also, if possible, I would like to know the simplest way to achieve this effect in Photoshop if anyone knows. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It kind of depends on the situation, but I'm guessing you don't wish to paint with this style. So as far as simple goes, I'd say search for `grunge brushes` and `brush stroke brushes` for photoshop. Then use those brushes by just clicking into different parts of the document. You may want to use black and white colors combined with lower opacities and  after the texture is done, add `layer adjustment`: `Hue/saturation` with the colorize option checked and/or `Gradient map`. You might want to also flatten, duplicate and change  the blend mode in the duplicated layer to something like `Overlay`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's watercolor mainly. Looks like the weeping angel (don't blink) has some inking on it to create the darker lines but that could be a heavy use of the watercolor paints as well.

You can find brushes as mentioned above searching (with quotes) "photoshop watercolor brushes". You can see the layering of the brush strokes which could be achieved by making sure the pressure or opacity of the brush was set to 30% or less. Bear in mind, this is not a drag to paint type of brush but one that someone created, usually with real paint, then scanned into the computer and made a brush out of.

When you paint this way, you set your opacity and click the mouse once placing the pixels on the workspace. You can also reverse the effect to get a real feel to it by using other brush strokes and the eraser tool set to very low so that you get the feeling of different lengths of bristles for the brush.

Here is a quick one I did, not the same style but you get the point:
[image: Watercolor demo]

And here is a link to a nice [collection of brushes](http://speckyboy.com/2011/05/05/38-watercolor-photoshop-brush-sets-950-brushes/).

Comment: thanks for the great set of brushes! will play around with them :)

Answer (score 1):

Grunge Image Effect

Here are some pretty old tutorials but still helpful

- http://pshero.com/photoshop-tutorials/photo-effects/photo-transfer-edge-effect
- http://psd.fanextra.com/tutorials/designing/design-a-grungy-floating-island/
- http://www.imarc.net/blog/97-ps_quickie_your_own_crazy_movie_poster
- http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-the-walking-dead-inspired-grungy-text-effect-in-adobe-photoshop--cms-22227